# Is "Whoever does not progress every day is in loss" good English?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

It is a quote from a not-English religious leader of many centuries ago. I like to know which rendering is the most natural. These have come to my mind:

1) **Whoever does not progress every day is in loss.**

2) **A man who has not progressed from yesterday to today is loss.**

3) **If you do not progress on a daily basis, you are a loser.**

4) **A man whose two days are the same is a loser.**

Which translation do you think is the best? How would you put this concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use the term *loser*. That word sounds like it belongs in an insult shouted on a middle school playground, not in a philosphical teaching from a religious sage.

How about something like this?

> **If you don't make any progress in a day, you're taking a step backwards**.

That seems to capture the essence of the saying while retaining a proverbial flavor.

An even better rendition has been suggested by our esteemed StoneyB:

> **If you're not moving forward you're moving backward**.

Comment: +1 Or "If you're not moving forward you're moving backward". Or, from Lewis Carroll, "It takes all the running you can do to keep in the same place."

Comment: @Stoney - I like yours better; you ought to make that an answer on its own.

Comment: Steal it then; I just polished yours a little. It would never have occurred to me without seeing yours.

Answer (score 2):

The answers by @J.R. and @StoneyB are excellent, and I just wanted to add my 2c to them.

"in loss", as used in this quote, seems to be pretty rare usage based on what my good friend Google told me. However, there are ways to still use "loss", to emphasize that lack of progress is the loss of something valuable - i.e. the opportunity to be a better person.

- Living without learning (or growing) every day is a loss.
- Time spent not learning (or growing) is lost time.
- To not learn (or grow) every day is to lose time.

Note that I'm avoiding the verb "progress". In many languages besides English, it's often used with the connotation of "to make personal progress", i.e. to learn and/or grow. It can also be used with that meaning in English, but it's not as common - usually it means "to move forward" in a direct or indirect sense:

- The project is progressing on schedule.
- The protest march progressed through the center of town, moving in the direction of Parliament.